# Custom View: swipe inside of scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I created a custom View with Canvas and made it interactivly with overwriteing onTouchEvent.
But my view is inside of a ScrollView. It losts the focus while i drag/swipe an item to the right side in my custom view and move my finger a little bit up or down. Then the ScrollView react and my view never get an ACTION_UP Event.

Is there a way to avoid that the scrollView-Parent scolls while i interact with my custom view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)

In your custom view, once it has detected the touch gesture is for it, call `scrollview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`. The scrollview will then ignore further events for the duration of the touch i.e. until it (the scrollview) receives an `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` event.

Comment: Wow. I searched for hours and it's so easy... Thank you.